# Recyclerview sort by current date

Tags: sorting, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In the recyclerview, I have data in the format dd/MM/yyyy with a period titled date.I want this data to list only the dates that are less than the current date.I am using sqlite as database.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `ORDER BY`  in your sql request. And should format date in milliseconds before pass it into database. Then, when you called data in recycler view use SimpleDateFormat for formatting date into dd/mm/yyyy. For current date use Calendar.getInstance.getDateInMillis

Comment: Hi, @Spectator. I rejected your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/31005489) because you are trying to add code highlighting by adding `\`\`\` kotlin`, but this adds extra indenting spaces to the whole code block. You can use `<!-- language: kotlin -->` instead, or remove extra spaces added by `\`\`\`` manually. But when the question contains a language tag, like [kotlin] here, this language highlighting is automatically applied to all code blocks, so this is redundant.